# Android Realm, Inserting One-to-Many - @PrimaryKey

Tags: android, realm

The official documentation has the following definition.

> RealmList are basically containers of RealmObjects, that behave very
>   much like a regular Java List. There is no limitation in Realm to
>   using the same object twice (or more) in different RealmList, and you
>   can use this to model both one-to-many, and many-to-many
>   relationsships.

So,

```
public class Email extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String address;
    private boolean active;
    // ... setters and getters left out
}

public class Contact extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String name;
    private RealmList<Email> emails;
    // ... setters and getters left out
}
```

How to avoid duplicate data? There are some way to avoid duplicate primarykey?

```
realm.beginTransaction();
Contact contact = realm.createObject(Contact.class);
contact.setName("John Doe");

Email email1 = realm.createObject(Email.class);
email1.setAddress("john@example.com");
email1.setActive(true);
contact.getEmails().add(email1);

Email email2 = realm.createObject(Email.class);
email2.setAddress("john@example.com");
email2.setActive(false);
contact.getEmails().add(email2);

realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: What kind of duplication are you trying to avoid ? 
inside the list or inside the database ?

If you're worried about database then I don't think database will have two copies of these two email objects. It would overwrite first email object with second one.

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo No. I have this issue too. I am saving genres for movies. Movie(One) to Genre(many), it will throw an exception if the genre exists or duplicated if genre_id is not the primary key